# Write `state.tree` instead of `state.xxxReducer.tree` in `mapStateToProps` (react redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have to write `mapStateToProps` like below

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    node: ownProps.info? state.TreeNodeReducer.tree[ownProps.info.path] : {}
  };
}
```

combine reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import TreeNodeReducer from './TreeNodeReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  TreeNodeReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducers/TreeNodeReducer.js

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE, GET_NODES } from '../constants/NodeActionTypes';

const initialState = {
  open: false,
  info: {} 
}

class NodeModel {
    constructor(path, type, right) {
        this.name = path;
        this.path = path;
        this.type = type;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

let lastId = 0;

function getFileList() {
  var testNodes = []
  for (var i=0; i< 3; i++) {
    testNodes.push(new NodeModel(lastId,'d', i.toString()))
    lastId++;
  }

  return testNodes
}


const getNodes = (state, action) => {
  var { path } = action
  var tree = state.tree ? state.tree : {}
  tree[path] = getFileList(path)
  return {
    ...state,
    tree:tree
  };
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_NODE:
      return { ...getNodes(state, action), open:true };
    case GET_NODES:
      return getNodes(state, action);
    case CLOSE_NODE:
      return {
        ...state,
        open:false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

because `state.TreeNodeReducer.tree` is a global state, which hold all node info, I want to access it by state directly.State return by a reducer would wrap by the reducer's name, which is not convenient for simple project.   [Office doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) don't provide the way.Any idea?

PS: I have to say I want to keep using `combineReducers`, I see some project not use it, directly pass reducer to store which can achieve my purpose but not good.

Comment: Could you please also show the TreeNodeReducer?

Comment: @Ashitaka I have update the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieving what you desire depends a bit on the state handled by the `TreeNodeReducer`.

If that reducer just handles the `tree` property, like this:

```
function treeNodeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { tree: action.tree, ... })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I'd say change the reducer to eliminate the `tree` property and merge it directly with the state, like this:

```
function treeNodeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.tree)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This way we can access the tree object in `mapStateToProps` with `state.treeNodeReducer`.

But this is still not what we want. We want to rename `treeNodeReducer` to `tree`. There are two solutions for that:

1. Either:

   ```
   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   import TreeNodeReducer from './TreeNodeReducer'

   const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     tree: TreeNodeReducer
   });

   export default rootReducer;
   ```
2. Or:

   ```
   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   import tree from './TreeNodeReducer'

   const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     tree
   });

   export default rootReducer;
   ```

This way we can access the tree object in `mapStateToProps` with `state.tree`.

Comment: Thanks! Since `treeNodeReducer` not handle just one action, and cope with 2 or 3 properties, so I should merge properties directly with the state, is that right? Seems not a pretty way but is the only way. uh...understand, thanks again.

Comment: I know it isn't pretty if you have other state besides `tree` being handled by the `TreeNodeReducer`. But if you look at the official doc examples, you can see that it's pretty normal for a reducer to directly return some state, instead of an object containing that state. Check the [combineReducers docs](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/combineReducers.md). There, the `counter` reducer returns a single number and `todos` returns a single array.

Comment: I suggest reading the docs on [Reducers and Designing the State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html). There you can observe the evolution from a single reducer into several, smaller reducers that each handle a small part of the whole state. For example, in the end, the `visibilityFilter` reducer returns a single string.